# Neo4j cypher query ORDER BY with parameters

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a simple cypher query and would like to modify it with parameters.

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.email = {searchString} return u ORDER BY {sortField} {sortOrder} SKIP {skipNumber} LIMIT {limitNumber}
```

Executing this query results in the following error:

```
Invalid input '{': expected whitespace, comment, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, IS, '^', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-', '=', "<>", "!=", '<', '>', "<=", ">=", AND, XOR, OR, DESCENDING, DESC, ASCENDING, ASC, ',', SKIP, LIMIT, LOAD CSV, START, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, CREATE, SET, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, WITH, CALL, RETURN, UNION, ';' or end of input (line 1, column 87 (offset: 86)) "MATCH (lc:LeadContact) WHERE lc.email = {searchString} return lc ORDER BY {sortField} {sortOrder} SKIP {skipNumber} LIMIT {limitNumber}"
```

If I remove "{sortField} {sortOrder}" and write static text (e.g., "ORDER by u.name ASC" the query executes smoothly:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.email = {searchString} return u ORDER BY u.name ASC SKIP {skipNumber} LIMIT {limitNumber}
```

Why does cypher not allow parameters here? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different `ORDER BY` or direction might require a different query plan. Currently you can only parameterize stuff that has no impact on the query plan. Because of the very same reason labels and relationship types are not parameterizable.

Comment: There is a way around it by adding an extra field in the RETURN.

Comment: It is so strange that this issue has remained in 2024, but I couldn't find any mention of this in the neo4j language guides (I checked Python) or the cypher manual. Even if it is present in the documentation, it is deeply hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Something that can be done is `ORDER BY field[$parameter]` using dynamic properties as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63195839/15761889) reply on a similar question.

Now, supposing that you have a query a little bit more complex, with two MATCH statements: if you need to also change the sort field, you could write something like this:

```
MATCH (u:User)
MATCH (v:Vehicle)
WHERE u.email = {searchString}

WITH coalesce(
  CASE WHEN {sortField} = "u.name" THEN u.name ELSE null END,
  CASE WHEN {sortField} = "v.brand" THEN v.brand ELSE null END,
  u.name // Provide a default sorting field
) AS orderField

RETURN u, v
ORDER BY orderField ASC SKIP {skipNumber} LIMIT {limitNumber}
```

As for the sorting order, you could use this neat little trick:

```
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN {sortOrder} = "ASC" THEN orderField ELSE null END ASC,
CASE WHEN {sortOrder} = "ASC" THEN null ELSE orderField END DESC
```

Of course, this comparison could be made easier to read if `{sortOrder}` was a boolean, something like `{ascending}`.

Comment: I know we're not supposed to write compliments here, but your workaround for the sorting order is just awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows, taking advantage of the fact that you can parametrise the return:

```
RETURN a,b,c,b[$sortField] AS sortField
ORDER BY sortField
```