# How to use a query parameter for ORDER BY?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query where I want the results sorted by a field determined by the user. Not an outlandish feature, I'd expect. But I can't figure out how to do this in Neo4J/Cypher.

This is the basic query:

```
MATCH (o:SomeThing)
ORDER BY o.id
SKIP 0
LIMIT 20
RETURN o
```

Pretty simple. Except of course `ORDER BY`, `SKIP` and `LIMIT` need to be supplied by the user, so we get this:

```
const query = `MATCH (o:SomeThing)
    ORDER BY $order
    SKIP $skip
    LIMIT $limit
    RETURN o`;

session.run(query, { order: 'o.name', skip: 0, limit: 20 });
```

This works fine for skip and limit, but `ORDER BY` doesn't work. It probably doesn't work because `order` contains a string, whereas we need a field expression. But how do I pass that as a parameter?

The docs aren't very helpful. It really sounds like this isn't possible, but that sounds hard to believe for such an obvious use case. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [dynamic property](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/expressions/#cypher-expressions-general) syntax.

For example, this should work:

```
const query = "
    MATCH (o:SomeThing)
    ORDER BY o[$propName]
    SKIP $skip
    LIMIT $limit
    RETURN o";

session.run(query, { propName: 'name', skip: 0, limit: 20 });
```

Comment: This is perfect. I was just getting the impression that this wasn't possible in Cypher, but this looks exactly like what I need. Looks like I could also use this in WHERE clauses like: `WHERE o[$propname] IN $param`.